# How do Scala collections use some variant types in contravariant position?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Consider a Scala collecton such as `List` or a trait such as `GenTraversible` and `GenTraversibleLike`. All of these are defined with a type `A` such that it is variant (e.g. `List[+A]`).

These types/traits have certain methods such as `contains(elem: A)` and `filter(pred: A => Boolean)`.

I don't understand why this is allowed---it seems the type `A` is appearing in a contravariant position, even though the class/trait declaration says `+A` (variant).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is in covariant position for both `contains` and `filter`.

The signature for `contains` is actually:

```
def contains[A1 >: A](elem: A1): Boolean
```

When a type variable is used on the right-side of a lower type bound, it is in covariant position.

With `filter`, the parameter is of type `A => Boolean`, i.e. `Function1[A, Boolean]`. `Function1` is contravariant in its first parameter, and the `Function1` itself is in contravariant position as the parameter to `filter`. Two contravariances combine to make covariance.

One way to get your head around this is image a `List[X]` where `X <: Y`. If this `List[X]` is cast to `List[Y]`, are those methods still type-safe? `contains` now requires that `A1` be a supertype of `Y`, which is actually a more stringent requirement. `filter` now requires a function `Y => Boolean`, which is also a more stringent requirement because the passed in function must be able to handle any `Y`, not just those that are instances of `X`. On the other hand, casting a `List[Y]` to a `List[X]` would not be type-safe. If `X` also subtypes `Z` but `Y` does not, and `Z` is used for `A1` in `contains`, then the type bound will be violated, because `Z >: Y` isn't true. For filter, the passed function would be `X => Boolean`, and couldn't safely be passed the instances of `Y` that the `List` contains. So, we can conclude that `A` is indeed in covariant and not contravariant position in these methods.

Comment: What do you mean by "position", with respect to variance?

Comment: @acjay A "covariant position" is one where only a covariant variable may appear, likewise for contravariance.

Answer (score 1):

This is allowed because for covariant types, the methods that take arguments can have a LOWER BOUND of T. Consider the following example:

```
trait myList[+T] {

  def prepend(elem: T): List[T] = new Cons(elem, this)
}
```

This won't work because you can't have a covariant type as an argument - you will get a compile time error. On the other hand, you can restrict the method parameter with a lower bound of T - the argument can be T or a supertype of T, instead of a subtype, like so

```
trait myList[+T] {

  def prepend[S >: T](elem: S): List[S] = new Cons(elem, this)
}
```